# How to have the same Geometry Node tab under the OSM configuration tab?

Tags: blender-osm

I'm new to Blender and I've been messing around with the OSM and the [Buildify](https://paveloliva.gumroad.com/l/buildify) plugins. I'm following a tutorial about how to use it but I found that there is one tab where it does not show on my Blender. What do I have to do to have the same Geometry Node tab under the OSM configuration tab?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: download the new version of blender-osm plugins.